# clojure partition list into equal piles

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a way to implement equal piles in a list that can take a list of N elements and split it in to M piles.  Any remainders are added one at a time to each pile. I feel like there might be something already out there.

```
List:  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
M = 5

[[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]]; divided into equal piles with   remainder [6 7 8 9]

[[1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9] [5]]; output
```

But the actual numbers in each pile I don't really care about.  As long as the (count element) is +/- of all others.

I found partion-all, but it doesn't deal with the remainder the way I need to, and I couldn't get the program to take the last element of the generated list and stick it in to the previous piles.

Answer (score 6):

#### `group-by`-based solution (no guarantees w.r.t. pile ordering)

If the items in the list might not be consecutive integers as obtained from `range`, you can apply the basic idea behind Diego's function to indices instead of the items themselves:

```
(defn piles [m xs]
  (->> xs
    (map-indexed (fn [i x] [(mod i m) x]))
    (group-by first)
    vals
    (mapv #(mapv peek %))))
```

Note that `group-by` will return a hash map for sufficiently large values of `m`, so this function cannot guarantee any particular ordering of the piles (in particular, shorter piles may arrive ahead of taller piles).

Example from the REPL:

```
(piles 5 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])
;= [[1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9] [5]]
(piles 5 [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i])
;= [[:a :f] [:b :g] [:c :h] [:d :i] [:e]]
```

#### `partition-all`-based solution alternating between piles

Alternatively, you can use `partition-all` and a custom version of `map` that only stops when *all* its inputs are empty:

```
(defn piles2 [m xs]
  (letfn [(mapv-all [f & colls]
            (loop [colls (map seq colls) ret []]
              (if (every? nil? colls)
                ret
                (recur (map next colls)
                       (conj ret
                         (mapv first (take-while some? colls)))))))]
    (->> xs
      (partition-all m)
      (apply mapv-all vector))))
```

This function always returns the piles in the "natural" order.

Example:

```
(piles2 5 [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i])
;= [[:a :f] [:b :g] [:c :h] [:d :i] [:e]]
```

#### `partition-all`-based solution preserving original item order

In response to the comment, here's a way to keep the original order of elements:

```
(defn piles3 [m xs]
  (let [cnt (count xs)
        l   (quot cnt m)
        r   (rem cnt m)
        k   (* (inc l) r)]
    (concat
      (partition-all (inc l) (take k xs))
      (partition-all l (drop k xs)))))
```

NB. this returns a seq of seqs; you could use `(mapv vec …)` to transform it into a vector of vectors.

Example:

```
(piles3 5 (range 32))
;= ((0 1 2 3 4 5 6) (7 8 9 10 11 12 13) (14 15 16 17 18 19) (20 21 22 23 24 25) (26 27 28 29 30 31))
(map count *1)
;= (7 7 6 6 6)
```

Comment: thanks! this is totally what I asked, and you anticipated me using list of lists for this! I was wondering how I can modify this to make it so that I get (piles 2 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]) 
; [[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7]], the ordering changed.  I thought it would be easy for me to see how to change it!

Comment: @user1639926 Just edited the answer to include a solution that works like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
(defn piles [xs m]
  (vals (group-by #(mod % m) xs)))
```

And then

```
(piles [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 5)
```

=> ([1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9] [5])

Answer (score 0):

A succinct - albeit slow - lazy solution:

```
(defn piles [n coll]
  (let [heads (take n (iterate rest coll))]
    (map (partial take-nth n) heads)))
```

For example

```
(piles 5 (range 1 10))
;((1 6) (2 7) (3 8) (4 9) (5))
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast eager version:

```
(defn piles [n coll]
  (loop [ans (vec (repeat n []))
         i 0
         coll coll]
    (if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
      (recur
        (update-in ans [i] conj x)
        (mod (inc i) n)
        xs)
      ans)))
```

... which returns a vector of vectors:

```
(piles 5 (range 1 10))
;[[1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9] [5]]
```